# Kendo UI DatePicker time issue

Tags: kendo-ui, telerik, timezone

I am experiencing a strange issue with the kendo datepicker.  I am defining it as:

```
<input data-role="datepicker" data-bind="value: selectedUser.HireDate" />
```

Everything works well locally, but when I deploy my app to Azure, I am getting the wrong time for the HireDate before the data is sent to the server.

For example: if I set the datepicker to 8/1/2016 and I break point the javascript function before I send the data to the server on my local machine I get Mon Aug 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time).
If I conduct the same experiment on the live site I get Mon Aug 01 2016 **17:00:00** GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time).  Once the data is passed to the server I get the wrong date because the server adds the 7 hours time zone offset and I ended up saving August 2nd in the database.

My understanding is that on the client the dates should always point to the local date and time regardless of where the server is located.  Furthermore, the datepicker should always have the hour set to 00:00:00, correct?

So,  why is the kendo datapicker widget adding 17 hours to the user selection when the site is deployed on the Azure server?

Any ideas on why this is happening are highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found what the problem is.  Apparently, the datepicker preserves whatever the time value was when you load the model into the widget.   In my case the date was saved in the database with time as 00:00:00 and when MVC convert it into local time it became 17:00:00 (-7:00 PST). Then when the user changes the date in the datepicker, the 17:00:00 stays with it.

I understand the conversion between the browser and the server, but I am still wondering why the datepicker widget keeps the hour in its value.  The datetimepicker should do that, but the datepicker should keep the time at 00:00:00.  This of course is my opinion.  Maybe there is a reason for this.  It will be interesting to hear someone from Telerik ellaborate.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is due to the different timezone and the fact that the date-object is actually a date-time-object, the javascript date-object stores the date based on your current timezone .
Once you send it to the server, it will be converted to UTC and the other way around. If you don't specify a time, 0:00 is passed as time and then converted as if it was being specified.

By default, if you create a new Date-object without specifying anything, it will use the browser's current time and timezone.
But, if you create a new Date with only year, month and day as parameters, it will pick 00:00:00 as time.